# Problem with custom registration fields in an multistore setup in magento

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I have 2 sites running on my magento platform.

For site2, I added new fields to the registration page and it works properly.

Now, I noticed that when I try to register in site1, on submit I am shown a validation message that the additional fields I have added for site2 are required.

How do I make sure that the additional fields added for site2, are asked only for site2 and not site1?

I have separate themes for both site1 and site2 and both of them have separate `register.phtml` files.

In the config.xml file for adding custom registration fields, I have this added:

```
<customer_account>
    <employee_id>
        <create>1</create>
        <update>1</update>
    </employee_id>
    <doj>
        <create>1</create>
        <update>1</update>
    </doj>
    <mobile_number>
        <create>1</create>
        <update>1</update>
    </mobile_number>
    <alternate_mail>
        <create>1</create>
        <update>1</update>
    </alternate_mail>
</customer_account>
```

which is under `<global>` tag. I assume Magento is reading this. How do I make sure magento reads this config file for a particular site/store? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the entire XML tree magento has compiled from all XML configuration files:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
die(Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode()->asXML());
```

Will present you with a single compiled XML of their entire tree, this may help in determining if your changes are being added.

Also be sure and checkout [Alan Storms CommerceBug](http://store.alanstorm.com/products/commerce-bug) as it has this functionality built-in.

Comment: Sorry if have not framed my question correctly. I have followed his tutorial and was able to see the entire xml tree. But i am looking for a suggestion where by my config xml is added only when a particular site/store is loaded and not for all the sites in my multi site setup. To be more specific, i have added a few custom  registation fields to one of my site. As it stands, though these fields donot appear in the frontend, they are being shown as required when users try to register in other sites. Is there a way to add custom registration fields just to one of my sites and not all of them?

Comment: I believe you are going to want to setup your fields in the second site's app/design/frontend/design/view/layout .xml instead of in your modules config.xml so Magento knows to only apply those fields to the second store view and not the first.

Comment: Is it possible to setup the fields through layout.xml ? Could you please point me to some article or post that shows this? Would be of great help, thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use the same XML in your layout XML files as they are all compiled into one tree.

Answer (score 1):

How I solved a similar situation is that I added system configuration options to allow me to set which custom field is enabled all the way down to the store view scope. This means I don't need to have separate phtml for the different stores, but can just use the same.

I've also created custom phtml 'widgets' - modelled on the Magento DOB, Gender and Name widgets. The custom widget block code has a 'isEnabled()' method that checks the config flag. In, say, my checkout/onepage/billing.phtml I can say:

```
<?php $_mywidget = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mycompany/customer_widget_mywidget') ?>
<?php if ($_mywidget->isEnabled()): ?>
....
<?php endif ?>
```

Hope this helps.